# fix fortify header manipulation issue

Tags: c#, fortify

Fortify showing header manipulation issue for following line of code

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + string.Format("{0}.txt", Request.QueryString["ImportResult"].ToString()));
```

How can I validate querystring

Comment: Fortify usually has pretty decent descriptions of the problems it's pointing out, and suggested fixes. Have you already reviewed their explanation, and if so, what part of it is giving you trouble?

Comment: which characters should I black list